# What would cause a deep vertical gorge in a mountainside, on Earth?

Tags: internal-consistency, earth, geology

I'd like earthquakes to cause deep gullies along some mountainsides of my planet. Here on earth, vertical fault scarps can form from earthquakes, but the examples I see online tend to be less gully - like and more sheer face like.

I need gullies. I do not want water to form these gullies. But, I am not certain earthquakes would be realistic.

The tectonics do not need to work the same on my planet, as on Earth, but I would like the idea to be grounded in reality.

Can seismic forces cause a series of regularly occurring large vertical gorge  features on mountainsides? Like 100 feet across and forty feet deep; the length of the mountain. Something you would not want to accidentally fall into.

Would rifting be a better geological explanation?

Comment: @AlexP: it's rare that this gets said but: your comment would be better suited as an answer.

Comment: @JoeBloggs: All right, made an answer, including a picture.

Comment: Welcome to the site, DPT. Please note that we generally encourage users to [hold off](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5023/6986) on accepting an answer for a while. The site has users located all around the world, and accepting an answer may discourage other users from potentially providing a better answer.

Comment: But, it *was* perfect. :-) Surely that's worth something.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The technical term for what you are looking for is a [graben](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graben) /`ˈgrɑːbən`/; there are many examples of Wikipedia. A good match for the kind of landscape sought in the question may be the [Basin and Range Province](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basin_and_Range_Province) covering *"much of the inland Western United States and northwestern Mexico"* (Wikipedia); *"it is defined by unique basin and range topography, characterized by abrupt changes in elevation, alternating between narrow faulted mountain chains and flat arid valleys or basins".

[image: Satellite photo of typical Basin and Range topography across central Nevada]

[Satellite photo of typical Basin and Range topography across central Nevada. NASA; public domain. Available on [Wikimedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basin_and_Range_Province#/media/File:Basin_range_province.jpg).]

Comment: Yep. Better as an answer. +1